# Modify the Size of an Android Spinner Drop down part Size?

Tags: android, spinner

how can i modify the size of the dropdown part of the spinner??
do i have to do that in XML or in the code itself?

Comment: Do you mean the row or the actual container which holds all of the rows? If you mean the row, then you should provide a custom layout for the dropdown row.

Comment: i mean the part which drops down: http://img853.imageshack.us/img853/8241/stackoverflow.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not change the size of spinner as it is default widget. But you can make it custom using background image. Here is my code:

```
<Spinner 
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop = "true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/placeCity"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:background="@drawable/myspinner_background"
/>
 <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageView1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner"
       android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner"
       android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:src="@drawable/down" />
```

> This is written in XML. And make another file called myspinner_background.xml in drawable folder. Inside that, write this code:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<stroke
    android:color="#f269be"
    android:width="2dp" />
<solid
    android:color="#ECC8EC" />
```

Answer (score 9):

In xml, I believe you set it with **android:dropDownWidth**. This worked for me:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dropDownWidth="dp_value_you_desire" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `Spinner` property which limits the height of the dropdown.

```
android:dropDownHeight="100dp"    <!--change 100dp to your requirement-->
```

you can also modify width...

```
android:dropDownWidth="100dp"   <!--change 100dp to your requirement-->
```

This works with `AutoCompleteTextView` as well.

Comment: There is no dropDownHeight option

Comment: @AhmetKorkmaz For some reason there's no autocomplete option. But if you write it yourself you'll see that it works. Also the attribute exists in the documentation