# Android - Issue with custom Spinner background

Tags: android, layout, spinner

I'm trying to give a custom background to my spinner. I've downloaded the HTC sense spinner design (Cf. following pictures) with the 9 patch format.

[image]
[image]

I've created a new XML file with the following code inside:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

         <item
             android:state_focused="true" 
             android:state_pressed="false" 
             android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_pressed" />

        <item
            android:state_focused="true" 
            android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_pressed" />

        <item
            android:state_focused="false" 
            android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_pressed" />

        <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_normal" />

    </selector>
```

And I've added a spinner to my layout with this code:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/my_spinner"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_spinner" />
```

But whereas being correctly displayed, I got the following format:

[image]

Did I make something wrong?

I hope you'll can help me.

Regards.

V.

Comment: Please check this link: [Spinner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923269/modify-the-size-of-an-android-spinner-drop-down-part-size/9923516#9923516) I've answered to the similar question. I hope it may helpful to you.

Comment: whats the problem...? It looks ok .. is it the height or what exactly is not going well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stretchable areas defined on your 9-patch seem wrong, and that is why your 9-patch are stretched like this. Have a look at [Nine-patch docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) and notice that the left-border defines what area should be stretched. I think you should also define a stretchable area below the "arrow" if you want the "arrow" to be centered.

If you do not know how to edit 9-patch you should use [draw9patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) it is included in the `AndroidSDK/tools`.

Comment: I've modified my 9 patch images and now, the arrow is centered. But my spinner still has a weird look...

Comment: explain "weird", post images.

Comment: Here it is: http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg809/scaled.php?server=809&filename=newam.png&res=medium

Comment: My spinner (the one in my app) looks like the 3rd one

Comment: this is how 9 patch are stretched. you can try different stretchable areas until you get the desired result or, maybe you need other drawable to fit your needs.

Comment: Ok, but how to get the second one?

Comment: you don't get to choose which one you get. the images displayed on the tool preview how the 9patch looks when it is stretched horizontally,vertically or along both axes.

Comment: I got a correct result since I edited the size of my 9 patch images for 34 px to 80px. Now the spinner is nice. How can I put rounded corners to my 9 patch?

Comment: I think you should also expand the stretchable areas.. to contain the corners too.